# Base Conversion in c

Tags: c

I found this program to do Base Conversions. What does the following line do in the program listing below?

```
printf("%c", base_digits[converted_number[index]]);
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char base_digits[16] =
   {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4','5', '6', '7','8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C','D', 'E', 'F'};

  int converted_number[64];
  long int number_to_convert;
  int  base, index=0;

/* get the number and base */
 printf("Enter number and desired base: ");
 scanf("%ld %i", &number_to_convert, &base);

/* convert to the indicated base */
while (number_to_convert != 0)
{
 converted_number[index] = number_to_convert % base;
 number_to_convert = number_to_convert / base;
 ++index;
}

/* now print the result in reverse order */
--index;  /* back up to last entry in the array */
printf("\n\nConverted Number = ");
for(  ; index>=0; index--) /* go backward through array */
{
 printf("%c", base_digits[converted_number[index]]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: printf("%c", base_digits[converted_number[index]]); converted_number[index] resolves to an index (0-15) which is used as an index into the base_digits array. So for example if converted_number[index] == 4 the that printf line would print '4'.

Answer (score 0):

The `converted_number` array contains the value of each digit in the converted number.

The `base_digits` array contains the character corresponding to each digit.  So `base_digits[converted_number[index]]` is getting the proper character for each digit in the specified base.